# Sublime text recognize functions that extend multiple lines

Tags: c, sublimetext3

This is probably answered a dozen times but I didn't know how to word it so google could help me.

How do I get sublime text to recognize and color code a function that extends multiple lines? Example:
`int myFunction(int param1, int param2) {}` Will be formatted correctly and color coded in sublime text. The following won't and just appears as white text in sublime.

`int myFunction
     (int param1, int param2) {}`

The above could obviously be fine on one line but with long function names that take many parameters it must be on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Sublime Text itself, but with the language grammar. These are files with `.tmLanguage` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assure the file suffix make sense with source code language, that is .c in your case.  When editing your c file do

```
View>Syntax>C
```

Comment: I don't think thats it. Everything else is recognized. Its when I try to put functions on multiple lines.